# Allocation of global variables C++

Tags: c++, memory, global-variables

It seems unclear as to where global variables get stored when declared different ways and which way is best?

For example, where are the variables stored in each example and what is their scope?

```
//Example 1 (at the top of a cpp file): 
Rectangle rect(15,12);

//Example 2:
Rectangle *rect = new Rectangle(15,12);
```

Comment: The ISO C++ standard does not mandate where things are stored, only how things behave Unless you have a specific implementation you want to talk about, the question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Where are the variables stored" is usually the wrong question. It varies between platforms and the language is designed to provide an abstraction over such details anyway.

Example 1 creates a `Rectangle` object with *static storage duration*. It will normally be destroyed automatically after `main` returns.

Example 2 creates a `Rectangle` object with *dynamic storage duration*. It will be destroyed whenever you call `delete` on the pointer (or, perhaps, call the destructor explicitly); otherwise it won't be destroyed. Informally people say objects of dynamic storage duration are "on the heap", but the implementation detail this evokes has a platform-dependent meaning.

Answer (score 1):

If the first is definied outside a function, it is going to be stored in the DATA segment. If it's defined in a function, it is going to be stored on the stack.

With the second (the pointer itself) it's the same, but the object the pointer is pointing to is going to be allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of oversimplification . . . .

An compiler will divide the compilation unit into sections:
- Executable data
- Read only data
- read write data
The linker will collect all the section with the same attributes together. At the end of the link process a global read/write data usually gets merges with read/write data.

This creates read/write data.

```
 Rectangle rect(15,12);
```

This creates read/write data for rect as well as executable data that calls new at startup.

```
Rectangle *rect = new Rectangle(15,12);
```

Ignoring debug information, local variables on have scope only during compilation. After compilation, local variables are only [relative] memory locations. Global variables remain identifiable after compilation. After linking, global variables essentially disappear.

(For simplicity I ignore universal symbols and shared libraries.)

Answer (score 0):

Where the variables "get stored" is implementation defined, and is not in the scope of the C++ standard, except as to the specific semantics of their scope.

Assuming that both declarations are statically-scoped, in both cases 'rect' will be stored at the static scope. In the second case, rect will refer to a heap-allocated object, and throughout the application's lifetime, the application may `delete` the pointer, and/or reassign it to point to some other instance of this class.